# C# How to open doc/docx in Word application to a specified page

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx

I want to open a doc/docx file to a specific page using Word.
Currently I use Process.Start() and can't figure it out with what to replace it for this job.

The purpose is just for viewing the document. I have a database based on fileLocation/pageNumber and this function must open the file directly to that page.

I would appreciate any solution/alternative.
Thank you!

Comment: you could give [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocX/1.0.0.19) library a go, might be easier.

Comment: Try to use google docs to show your file:  `<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.domain.com/yourfile.docx&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Comment: The Document.Goto method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836585(v=office.14).aspx is the way I'd go.

Comment: Ricardo: OP said "using Word" in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you concidered workinig with interop? If so check the following

[how can we open a word file with specific page number in c sharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870797/how-can-we-open-a-word-file-with-specific-page-number-in-c-sharp)

Another solution would be to use a bookmark and navigate there as show in

[How do I use the Microsoft Word API and Bookmarks feature to programmatically open a Word document to a specific location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646319/how-do-i-use-the-microsoft-word-api-and-bookmarks-feature-to-programmatically-op)